# Raspberry PI 4 PoE+ Hat Not Working

Tags: pi-4, poe

I have recently gotten a new Raspberry PI 4b, within minutes of unboxing I made the mistake of accidentally breaking the USB power connector, which for some reason was not attached correctly. I figured, okay, this could be worse and I could use a PoE hat to power my board, so I decided to go for that. After purchasing the required PoE hat, a PoE-supported ethernet cable, and PoE supported switch, I decided to connect them up. Once connected, the raspberry pi showed no sign of life at all.

If I use the GPIO Pins to power the pi, it does turn on but does not boot into the OS on the micro sd card.

Does anyone have any input as to what I should do?

Comment: Return the Pi to the supplier for replacement under warranty.

Comment: *"a PoE-supported ethernet cable"* so, an ethernet cable?? - *"PoE supported switch"* - what make and model - but I agree, if you received a faulty product, get it replaced